# How to copy a stack trace from the chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Suppose I get a stacktrace like this in the console:

[image]

How can I copy the stacktrace preserving the formatting?

When I copy this stacktrace I get one long line:

`VM1130:2 Foobar not foundplayer.store.registerListener @ VM1130:2logErrorsInCallback @ magic_store:221registerListener @ magic_store:240registerListenerThis @ magic_store:246(anonymous function) @ VM1130:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ (program):878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ (program):811InjectedScript.evaluate @ (program):667`

Is there a way to copy a stack trace in a more structured way?

Comment: I think you used `console.error` in the screenshot. I don't have a solution for that, it's something that should be fixed by Chrome. You get the same issue when throwing an exception, but in that case you can click on the ellipsis after the error to show a copy-able stack trace: `VM374:2 Uncaught Error: test(…)`

Comment: There's an existing issue for this on the Chromium bug tracker https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532531

Answer (score 2):

Copy-pasting seems to format OK now. Just copied this from an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: osdlfm is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at ad.js:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.n (ad.js:12)
```

The stack trace that shows up after I expand the error formats OK, too:

```
(anonymous) @ VM183:1
(anonymous) @ ad.js:12
n @ ad.js:12
```

[image: console stack trace]

Version info:

- Google Chrome:    63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Revision: 2e6edcfee630baa3775f37cb11796b1603a64360-refs/branch-heads/3239@{#709}
- OS:   Mac OS X